# Python module loading error for external terminal only

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VScode v1.65.1 Python debugging starting returning a FileNotFoundError when loading modules while using  "console": "externalTerminal", but not when "console": "integratedTerminal". The FileNotFoundError identifies the missing file as moduleName.pysa rather than moduleName.py; so I am not sure why the extension is changing. Also note the *.json debug config includes a "env": {"PYTHONPATH": \additional\path\}, entry, which may factor into the issue.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: Are you using `PowerShell` in the `integratedTerminal`? While `externalTerminal` only support `CMD`. If you can provide more information will be much better.

Comment: I am not using PowerShell. Why is VScode looking for moduleName.pysa and not moduleName.py?

Comment: It's FileNotFoundError error instead of module not found error?

Comment: Correct: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\path\\to\\working\\directory\\modulename.pysa'

Comment: Could you find it in your code?

Comment: Find what? The error is stating the script I am running is not found because the debugger is changing the working file name from script.py to script.pysa.

Comment: Any file you will run across this kind problem? Could you attach a screenshot of it?

Comment: Traced it back to something in the launch.json, replaced with launch file from another project and working now.